# Call to a member function setPageSize() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.7, database, ce-1.7.0.2, collection, grid

**How to use query to get result in Magento admin grid & set into collection?**

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query="MY_SQL_QUERY";
$result = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
$this->setCollection($result);
```

This is showing error as **Call to a member function setPageSize() on a non-object**

Comment: Refer these articles 1). http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: 2). http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/26/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`$result`* is not  an object of magento library class  `Varien_Data_Collection`.

`SetPageSize()`  works whenever **a collection is instance of**  `Varien_Data_Collection` class.

If you **want to use this function** then you need convert you  that collection **`($result )`** to *`Varien_Data_Collection`* .Then  setPageSize() will work.

> ```
> $collection = new Varien_Db_Collection();
> foreach($result as $row){
>     $rowObj = new Varien_Object();
>     $rowObj->setData($row);
>     $collection->addItem($rowObj);
> }
>
>
> $collection->setPageSize($size)
> ```

See more detail Check out [Alan Storm blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_collections)

Comment: This is a good approach if you explicitly **not** want to use the Magento methods to fetch data into a grid. Just be aware that setPageSize() and other collection modifiers, such as filters won't do anything if you use a custom query like that. You will have to take care about filters and pagination yourself.

Comment: @fschmengler,i guess that other way we can do  that change  Query to  resource Model Collection and   load this custom collectin using load() function & BeforeLoad().Just like report

Comment: @fschmengler,did you get my point? what Would be your thought on this topc

Comment: Yes. To be clear, your answer is good, I just wanted to highlight possible problems because we don't know if this is really what OP wants, or if he just does not know better than writing plain SQL. In this case, the tutorial links in the comment are a better place to start

Comment: It seems correct but getting error as Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Db_Collection' not found.

Comment: Thanks. Used Varien_Data_Collection instead Varien_Db_Collection. Now able to see grid.

Comment: @Amit What should be in variable $size? Currently getting all records in one page.

Comment: This is numeric value. it is no of item which will show on per page

Comment: I tried ways but couldn't make $collection->setPageSize($size) to work . On pagination in grid still having issues (All record showing in first page).